# Update reference index in fields with rendertype inputLink

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

Links to files or images in fields which use the renderType inputLink (e.g header_link in the normal content elements) do not update the reference index when the content element is saved.

My TCA:

```
'config' => [
'type' => 'input',
'renderType' => 'inputLink',
'size' => 50,
'max' => 1024,
'eval' => 'trim',
'fieldControl' => [
    'linkPopup' => [
        'options' => [
             'title' => '',
        ],
    ],
],
'softref' => 'typolink'
```

(the same as in header_link in the content elements)

Is there a possibility to force the correct handling of the reference index? The editors can't see which files are linked and which not, so they can delete the files in file module without error message.

Thanks

Comment: I didn't found a solution until now. I made a work around: one field with inputfield and linkPopup for Links to pages and external links and a media field only for files. Media field properly updates the reference index.

Comment: Is it possible to add class for `CSS-Class`  for renderType "InputLink" field sane as we add class for RTE link? https://prnt.sc/vd2gtu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this bug was fixed with TYPO3 9.7.12: 
https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/62205